# How to change response error to success response?

Tags: angularjs

Can I change error response (for example timeout) to success response in interceptor?

I try to cache response when success and return cached response when I get error.
I tried the following:

```
{
  response: function (response) {
      cache[response.config.url] = response;
  }, 
  responseError: function (rejection) {
    if (cache[rejection.config.url] != null) {
       $q.resolve(cache[rejection.config.url]);
    }
  return rejection;
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  response: function (response) {
      cache[response.config.url] = response;
  }, 
  responseError: function (rejection) {
    if (cache[rejection.config.url] != null) {
       $q.resolve();
       return cache[rejection.config.url];
    }
  return rejection;
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps explain what the original error was as well?